# Copying paramter inside Generic Type Parameter messing up around mark

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Why everytime im copying a model inside Generic Type Parameter it messed up arounding marks.

E.g. :

[image]

And if i copy\paste my model inside **Query<>** :

[image]

It gives extra space and messing it up. Now if hit Ctrl+z , VS removes those spaces.

[image]

Is this a normal behavior ? Im using Visual studio 2019.